# Filling a Pandas DataFrame column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of calls received per month for my business and am trying to split them up into if they were called back, scheduled, or cancelled. I am trying to create functions that evaluate based on meeting conditions how many in each category there were for each month.

For example, I want to fill a new column `Calls Scheduled` based on if the call was marked as scheduled. The idea is to iterate through all the rows and append to a list if this condition is met, then the length of the list becomes the value in `Calls Scheduled`.

What I have:

```
def scheduled(df_to_iterate, df_to_output, month):
    calls_scheduled = []
    
    for row in df_to_iterate:
        if df_to_iterate['Month'] == month:
            if df_to_iterate['Scheduled'] != np.nan:
                calls_scheduled.append(1)
        
    df_to_output.loc[month, 'Calls Scheduled'] = len(calls_scheduled)
    
scheduled(df2021, df, 'March')
```

I have two dataframes. `df2021`  contains all calls received and marked as called back, scheduled, or cancelled. `df` contains the total calls of each month by year and is what should be receiving the `Calls Scheduled` column.

Here is an example of data in `df2021`:

[image: df2021]

And here is the output `df` with the new `Calls Scheduled` column:

[image: output df]

After running the function, I receive a ValueError. I assume it is something basic, but I can't figure it out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 11
      7                 calls_scheduled.append(1)
      9     df_to_output.loc[month, 'Calls Scheduled'] = len(calls_scheduled)
---> 11 scheduled(df2021, df, 'March')

Cell In[34], line 5, in scheduled(df_to_iterate, df_to_output, month)
      2 calls_scheduled = []
      4 for row in df_to_iterate:
----> 5     if df_to_iterate['Month'] == month:
      6         if df_to_iterate['Scheduled'] != np.nan:
      7             calls_scheduled.append(1)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Post a small sample input dataframe along with the desired output dataframe. With pandas, there's almost certainly a cleaner approach than a convoluted loop.

Comment: @tdy Edited the post with both the input and output dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count match values of masks use `sum`, `True`s are processing like `1`:

```
def scheduled(df_to_iterate, df_to_output, month):
    count = ((df_to_iterate['Month']==month) & df_to_iterate['Scheduled'].notna()).sum()
    df_to_output.loc[month, 'Calls Scheduled'] = count
    return df_to_output
```

If need count each month aggregate `sum` and mapping by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
def scheduled(df_to_iterate, df_to_output):
    s = df_to_iterate['Scheduled'].notna().groupby(df_to_iterate['Month']).sum()
    df_to_output['Calls Scheduled'] = df_to_output.index.map(s)
    return df_to_output
```

And for 3 new columns solution is:

```
def all_calls(df_to_iterate, df_to_output):
    cols = ['Called','Scheduled','Completed']
    df1 = df_to_iterate[cols].notna().groupby(df_to_iterate['Month']).sum()
    df_to_output = df_to_output.join(df1.add_prefix('Calls '))
    return df_to_output
```

Comment: Very good. I ultimately went with your second solution. I used a variation of it to solve for the other columns and lumped them into one function. The third solution didn't work in my case because each column had different conditions that needed to be met.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use any loop. Can you try this:

```
def scheduled(df_to_iterate, df_to_output, month):
    calls_scheduled = len(df_to_iterate[(df_to_iterate['Month']==month) & (df_to_iterate['Scheduled'].notnull())])
    df_to_output.loc[month, 'Calls Scheduled'] = len(calls_scheduled)
```

**Note**: In your function, you are getting an error because `df_to_iterate['Month']` returns a series not a string value.

Comment: This is very good. It returned an error though because ```len()``` was called a second time. Simply removing the second ```len()``` solved the problem